# Codeigniter library "A3M" working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-a3m

I have installed this two three days before (so newbie for it). Twitter and facebook logins are workng fine.

http://articlecon.com/phpdemo/sbid/account/sign_in

Iam little bit confused in A3M login process.  I think that when user clicks on facebook, it takes user to facebook login. After successful login it takes back to the original website.

After that I don't see any user information in session from facebook. Facebook table (in database) is empty.

Can soem one guide me, what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you find that you do everything correctly but you are not logged in or no info is populate, it could be that the data being sent back to your server is not being saved (in the cache folder).

Make sure to `chmod` your cache folder (for your nonce's) to 777 or `chown` it to your apache/browser user for read/write permissions.

I have seen in the past that instances don't function well / break when they nonce cannot be saved after a successful handshake, so everything else after it fails (like db updates).